# IOS10 and Sharepoint 2013 compatibility

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, video, apple-ios

There are so many videos on our SharePoint 2013 site. But the problem is, when we connect to our site from mobile devices (O.S : IOS10) videos aren't displayed. We were able to watch videos with previous versions of iOS.
Please help.